# Avoid template mess when importing base class constructors of heavily templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, base-class, using-directives

This is just short inquiery if it is at all possible to somehow import base class constructors without all the template bloat. Consider this example where I'm inheriting from a templated `std::variant`:

```
template <typename StringType, typename Allocator>
class JSON : public std::variant<std::monostate,
                        std::unordered_map<StringType, JSON<StringType, Allocator>, std::hash<JSON<StringType, Allocator>>, std::equal_to<StringType>, Allocator>,
                        std::vector<JSON<StringType, Allocator>, Allocator>, 
                        bool,
                        double,
                        StringType>
{
public:

    using std::variant<std::monostate,
                        std::unordered_map<StringType, JSON<StringType, Allocator>, std::hash<JSON<StringType, Allocator>>, std::equal_to<StringType>, Allocator>,
                        std::vector<JSON<StringType, Allocator>, Allocator>, 
                        bool,
                        double,
                        StringType>::variant;
};
```

You can see that there's quite a bit of bloat which makes it rather unreadable and error prone. Can this be avoided? The reason I'm asking is because I think I once heard that you can somehow skip template parameters within a templated class as the compiler can imply what you meant.

**Clarification**:

Essentially I'm just looking for a way to not writing the same template mess *twice*. I have tried `using variant::variant` which doesn't work. But there might be other ways around this and any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well? Did you try to determine if the rumors you heard are true? It should take no more than a second, or two and then you can go from there?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It doesn't work with just using variant::variant as I have tried that. But this can't be the bottom of it x_X

Comment: Add an alias?  `using base_t = your_big_type; using base_t::base_t;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes but then I have to template the type alias and essentially I still have to write it twice so I wouldn't exactly call that a "solution". EDIT: I know what you mean: I would only have to use two template parameters. That is better yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) from the base class won't be found by unqualified lookup because the base class is a template that depends on template parameters of the derived class. Let's qualify that name:

```
template <typename StringType, typename Allocator>
class JSON : public std::variant<std::monostate,
                        std::unordered_map<StringType, JSON<StringType, Allocator>, std::hash<JSON<StringType, Allocator>>, std::equal_to<StringType>, Allocator>,
                        std::vector<JSON<StringType, Allocator>, Allocator>, 
                        bool,
                        double,
                        StringType>
{
private:
    using MyBase = typename JSON::variant;

public:
    using MyBase::MyBase;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v4bdafMre)

Comment: @OP I'd recommend accepting this answer rather than mine, unless this is a pattern you're using all over the place

Comment: This! I was looking for this. Then you might as well do just `using JSON::variant::variant` right?

Comment: @glades MSVC doesn't accept `using JSON::variant::variant;`. My own preference would be to add an alias for clarity anyway.

Comment: Finally a sane solution! Although the question is a duplicate. I won't vote to  close, because of this excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could write an alias template to factor out some of the repetition:

```
template <template <class...> class Temp, class StringType, class Allocator>
using variant_for = std::variant<std::monostate,
                        std::unordered_map<StringType, Temp<StringType, Allocator>, std::hash<Temp<StringType, Allocator>>, std::equal_to<StringType>, Allocator>,
                        std::vector<Temp<StringType, Allocator>, Allocator>, 
                        bool,
                        double,
                        StringType>;

template <typename StringType, typename Allocator>
class JSON : public variant_for<JSON, StringType, Allocator>
{
public:
    using variant_for<JSON, StringType, Allocator>::variant;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick idea: use inheritance to inherit that name

```
template <typename StringType, typename Allocator>
class JSONbase
{
public:
    using JSONStr = JSON<StringType, Allocator>;
    using variant = std::variant<std::monostate,
                        std::unordered_map<StringType, JSONStr, std::hash<JSONStr>, std::equal_to<StringType>, Allocator>,
                        std::vector<JSONStr, Allocator>, 
                        bool,
                        double,
                        StringType>::variant;
}

template <typename StringType, typename Allocator>
class JSON : 
    public JSONbase<StringType, Allocator>,
    public typename JSONbase<StringType, Allocator>::variant
{
   using variant::variant;
};
```